# When may it make sense to not have an index on a table and why?

Tags: oracle

For Oracle and being Relative to application tuning, when may it make sense to not have an index on a table and why?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is a cost associated to having an index:

- it takes up disk space
- it slows down updates (index needs to be updated as well)
- it makes query planning more complex (slightly slower, but more importantly increased potential for bad decisions)

These costs are supposed to be offset by the benefit of more efficient query processing (faster, fewer I/O).

If the index is not used enough to justify the cost, then having the index will be negative.

Answer (score 2):

In particular, if your data distribution is low (think flags like 'Y' and 'N'), indexes won't help much.  Think of it this way: if the number of distinct values in an index is low, the optimizer will probably choose not to use the index. An interesting aside is that if the column in the index is null, it might be much faster if your query criteria include actual values as nulls aren't indexed, which means that only the actual values (non null) are in that particular index,thereby not evaluating most of the rows in the table.  In the "is null" case, it will never use an index - if you have a query with a "where" clause like "where mytable.mycolumn is null", abandon all indexes ye who enter here.

Answer (score 1):

If a table has very little data (small number of rows) then it doesn't serve you to use an index. An index makes it quick to search on a specific attribute and if the application you are working with doesn't need a fast lookup then using an index does very little for you.

Comment: You'd be surprised how an index on a small table can make a big difference, e.g. if the table is queried very frequently. A full index scan might only need to read 1 block, whereas reading a table requires reading at least 2 blocks.